# On hover effect sub category show and slide towards right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, jsfiddle, mousehover

What I want is, when mouse cursor hovers on category list, show the subcategory and slide towards right side, same like as [daraz.pk](https://www.daraz.pk/) and [JSFiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kewax.jpg)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/5msq8wa3/1/ Plese see the code here

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses jQuery to grab the index of the `li` element being hovered over and displays the sub-menu with the respective index:

https://jsfiddle.net/pdgxuvse/4/

---

I think you're on the right track with nesting the sub-menu alongside the element you hover over to display it, though... so maybe disregard that part.

In that case you'll want to grab the element's parent and then the sub-menu element within it and disregard the index variable thing.

Maybe give that a shot and feel free to ask for help :)

Answer (score 0):

add following class in your CSS to show menu on hover. Now you need to edit class of child UL too.

```
.category_menu li:hover ul{
   display:block;
}
.right_sliding {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 40%;
top: 0;
background: #ffffff;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 20px;
```

}

Comment: Brother same like as daraz.pk see the link below               https://www.daraz.pk/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .category_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.category_menu > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
.right_sliding {
  display: none;
}
.category_menu li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa.fa-arrow-right {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 7px 0 0;
}
.category_menu > li > ul {

    position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
    right: -69px;
    top: 6px;
}
.category_menu > li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="category_menu">
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone fa fa-female"></span>
    <span class="cat_name">Womens Fashion</span>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="right_sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Women1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Women1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Women1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Women1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Women1</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone fa fa-male"></span>
    <span class="cat_name">Men Fashion</span>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="right_sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone fa fa-mobile"></span>
    <span class="cat_name">Phones</span>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="right_sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone fa fa-home"></span>
    <span class="cat_name">Home Appliences</span>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="right_sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icone fa fa-desktop"></span>
    <span class="cat_name">Computing</span>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="right_sliding">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Computing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Computing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Computing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Computing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Computing</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```